# How to show some html after featured image?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a related post code and I wants place it just after featured image on single post page. I have tried,

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wcr_related_posts', 10, 0 ) ;
```

but it doesn't work as I want to show content. It does show content at about proper place but the sidebar is not moving,  just content is being shown a bit below and I also want the sidebar to come below due to code that wcr_related_posts generates. 
I have not been able to find a hook that actually works that way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the 'the_content' filter:

```html
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_featured_image', 20 );

function insert_featured_image( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single'), $content, 1 );
    return $content;
}
```

Get the more details and examples as follow link : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61272/how-do-i-add-the-featured-image-to-the-content-after-the-first-paragraph

Comment: That might be of help but in my case I wants to add something after featured Image. Not before . :)